# How to convert minutes to HH:MM format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have query, which has to give the minutes as HH:MM format.

```
SELECT (cast(SUM(convert(int,total)) / 60  as varchar(5))+':' + 
        RIGHT('0' +cast(sum(convert(int,total) % 60) as varchar(2)),2)) 
FROM (SELECT  CASE(clnt_cntLngth)
          WHEN 0 THEN '15'
          WHEN 1 THEN '30'
          WHEN 2 THEN '60'
          WHEN 3 THEN '120'
          WHEN 4 THEN '300'
          ELSE '0' END as total  from dbo.clientInfo) as tbl`
```

which is referred from [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0726b6fb-c7ec-4ff3-930b-93c057c9639c/convert-minutes-to-hours?forum=sqlintegrationservices). It is giving good results for some values and not for some values. I don't know why. for example See the bellow results Images.
This is giving write ans [image]

ans this is giving wrong output [image]
what makes difference between those. Can  anyone suggest any more ways to do this for exact output. I did not change anything. 1st one is write answer ans second one has to be 1:00 but it is showing 1:60.

Comment: Note `SQL` is not the same as `SQL Server`!

Comment: Do you want an approach for that 5 cases?

Comment: I have a int field which will have only 0 to 4 numbers. Those 5 cases are working fine and giving exact minutes. I just want to convert them into hh:mm format. that's all.

Comment: @CenBan, now the updated solution should provide you correct hours and minutes .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[IntToMinutes]
(
    @m int
)
RETURNS nvarchar(20)
AS  
BEGIN

    DECLARE @c datetime
    DECLARE @c1 datetime
    SELECT @c =dateadd(mi,0,'00:00')              
    select @c1 = dateadd(mi,@m,'00:00')         

     return CONVERT(varchar(10),DATEDIFF(hh, @c, @c1) ) + ':' +
     CONVERT(varchar(10),DATEDIFF(mi,DATEADD(hh,DATEDIFF(hh, @c, @c1),@c),@c1) )
    end
```

Comment: It is giving an exception as  Type time is not a defined system type.

Comment: This IntToMinutes Function is working fine..  please test it and let me know if you find any issue..

Comment: try to call the IntToMinutes function with 568978.. giving wrong output. I have changed samllint to int in the function. even it is smallint, it has to work upto 32767. It is not giving exact output for 32767 too

Comment: Looks like issue is with dateadd function (may be its using smallint internally),let me check..

Comment: almost to get the solution.. the issue is once it cross the 24 hours it increase the day.. and as we are showing only hours and minutes its not showing correct hours.. doing changes :)

Comment: What about handling negative values?.Try select [dbo].[IntToMinutes](-1)